# Pandas- Function is overwriting original DF even though I am maniuplating copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a function to categorize data in bins in a df. I have made the function, and am first extracting numbers from a string, and replacing the column of text with a column of numbers.

**The function is somehow overwriting the original dataframe, despite me only manipulating a copy of it.**

```
def categorizeColumns(df):

    newdf = df
 
    if 'Runtime' in newdf.columns:
        for row in range(len(newdf['Runtime'])):
            strRuntime = newdf['Runtime'][row]
            numsRuntime = [int(i) for i in strRuntime.split() if i.isdigit()]
            newdf.loc[row,'Runtime'] = numsRuntime[0]
    
return newdf

df = pd.read_csv('moviesSeenRated.csv')
newdf = categorizeColumns(df)
```

The original df has a column of runtimes like this [34 mins, 32 mins, 44 mins] etc, and the newdf should have [33,32,44], which it does. **However, the original df also changes outside the function.**

**Whats going on here? Any fixes?** Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Seems like I wasn't making a copy, I needed to do

```
df.copy()
```

Thank you all!

Comment: You aren't making a copy anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't actually making a copy of the dataframe in the line `newdf = df`. To make a copy, you could do `newdf = df.copy()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not making a copy of dataframe. What you did on `newdf = df` is called reference.

You have to `.copy()` your dataframe.

```
def categorizeColumns(df):
    newdf = df.copy()
 
    if 'Runtime' in newdf.columns:
        for row in range(len(newdf['Runtime'])):
            strRuntime = newdf['Runtime'][row]
            numsRuntime = [int(i) for i in strRuntime.split() if i.isdigit()]
            newdf.loc[row,'Runtime'] = numsRuntime[0]
    return newdf

df = pd.read_csv('moviesSeenRated.csv')
newdf = categorizeColumns(df)
```